# Wrong CSS validation error? Aptana studio vs W3-Validator

Tags: css, validation, aptana, w3c-validation

```
#header ul li a[title="Über uns"] {
    background-image:url(images/header.jpg);
}
```

is said to be an lexical error by Aptana studio because of the Ü in the first line. The W3-Validator says its valid CSS, and also the Browsers understand. So its a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as long as your files are saved and the page is delivered with an encoding that supports german umlauts like "Ü" (`utf-8`, for example), everything is fine. if so, and Aptana studio still shows an error, it's a bug in Aptana studio.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for this, if your url is in english:

`#header ul li a[href~="about"] {`

I think, the Aptana devs just forgot the Umlauts.